# Google Play Console Open test release error "You need to add a full description"

Tags: google-play-console

I'm trying to create an open test for my Android game on Google Play Console.
When I click to "Review and roll out release" button it shows me "You need to add a full description"
error. I can't find anywhere to write that description. How can I enter full description.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I asked to Google Play Developer Support, it answered like below

In order to add a full description to your application, kindly login to your Play Console account > Select an app > Grow > Store Presence > Main store listing.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Console -> Dashboard -> Set up your app -> at the bottom "Set up your store listing"